# How to migrate from Parallels to VirtualBox?

Tags: migration, parallels-desktop, virtualbox

I've tried Parallels and it's great but I still find it quite "expensive" so I would like to try out VirtualBox.

Is there a way to migrate my Parallels installation to VirtualBox?

The versions:

- MacOs X 10.7.4
- Parallels 7
- VirtualBox 4.2.1

I've read some articles but they're quite old and don't match with my versions. Any help?

Comment: What do you want to migrate? Existing virtual machines?

Comment: If you want to migrate existing VMs, this will depend on the operating system running inside them. On the surface it's just moving/converting the disk images, but you're likely to run into driver problems with some OSes.

Comment: Yep, exactly. I would like to move my Win7 installation from Parallels to VB.

Comment: Are you running Parallels on a Boot Camp partition, or a dedicated Parallels virtual machine file?